# IOS TableView display issue when Scrolling Vigeriously

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Having a weird issue that is happening randomly.  When scrolling and coming back to a cell the cell will be in it's un-filled state.  See some images below of what is happening, here is my tableview delegates:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)[datas count]);
    return [datas count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    //NSLog(@"%@",[sects objectAtIndex:section]);
    return [self cleanText:[sects objectAtIndex:section]];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //return [datas count];
    //NSLog(@"%ld",(long)[[datas objectAtIndex:section] count]);
    return (NSInteger)[[datas objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    HHCellPlaceOrder *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //NSLog(@"Method Called");

    //Get NSDictionary for Cell
    NSDictionary *dict = [[datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.lblSku.text = [dict objectForKey:@"itemnumber"];
    cell.lblDescription.text = [dict objectForKey:@"description"];

    cell.lblSize.text = [dict objectForKey:@"itemsize"];
    cell.lblUnitCost.text = [dict objectForKey:@"netcost"];
    cell.lblQtyOnHand.text = [dict objectForKey:@"inventory"];

    cell.lblCost.text = [dict objectForKey:@"costfield"];

    cell.txtQty.text = [dict objectForKey:@"qtyfield"];

    if ([cell.txtQty.text isEqualToString:@"0"] == NO) {
        cell.cellBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        //cell.lblUPC.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    } else{
        cell.cellBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        //cell.lblUPC.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }

    CGRect frame = cell.cellBG.frame;
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"showBar"] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        cell.img_bar.hidden = NO;
        cell.lblUPC.hidden = NO;
        cell.lblUPC.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        //Bar Code...
        NKDUPCABarcode *bar = [NKDUPCABarcode alloc];
        bar = [bar initWithContent:[dict objectForKey:@"UPC"]];
        UIImage *i = [UIImage imageFromBarcode:bar];
        cell.img_bar.image = i;
        cell.img_bar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.lblUPC.text = [dict objectForKey:@"UPC"];

        frame.size.height = 158;
    } else{
        cell.img_bar.hidden = YES;
        cell.lblUPC.hidden = YES;

        cell.img_bar.image = nil;
        cell.lblUPC.text = @"";

        frame.size.height = 55;
    }
    cell.cellBG.frame = frame;

    return cell;
}
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return nil;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *dict = [[datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"showBar"] isEqualToString:@"1"]){
        return 158.0f;
    } else{
        return 55.0f;
    }
}
```

Images - links since I can't post images yet :(

Normal View - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14627145/normallook.jpg

After Some Scrolling Example - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14627145/WeirdCell1.jpg

I appreciate any help I can get! :D

Comment: My Custom Cell - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14627145/CellImage.jpg

Comment: Sounds like `dict` is `nil`. Can you verify this? When and how is `datas` populated?

Comment: Not getting any nil exceptions....I just optimized another part of the code and haven't seen the issue again my fingers are crossed it was something weird....

Comment: FYI, sending a message to `nil` doesn't thrown an exception.

Comment: It seems the issue was I was updating the cell (not only the array holding the data) that was causing the issue...maybe a lock issue or something.  Anyway that fixed that issue, but now the cell doesn't update all the time without scrolling up and back down after I update the values.  I am calling [table reloadData]; but it still doesn't redraw.  Is there another method I can use that will reprocess everything?

Comment: `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`